# DB2 : Implement LAG ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING

Tags: sql, datetime, db2, window-functions, sql-null

How could LAG(COL1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TMST ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) can be implemented in DB2, where it is not supported.

I mean, I want to derive a column (L_A_DATE) based on LAG value and derived column should continue to have the previous value until the existing column is not null

```
ID  COL1          STATUS         A_DATE          TMST
1   2020-08-08    OPEN            NULL        <current time>
1   2020-08-10    APPROVED     2020-08-09     <current time>
1   2020-08-13    OPEN            NULL        <current time>
1   2020-08-13    A_OPEN          NULL        <current time>
2   2020-08-08    OPEN            NULL        <current time>
2   2020-08-13    A_OPEN          NULL        <current time>
2   2020-08-15    APPROVED     2020-08-14     <current time>
2   2020-08-16    OPEN            NULL        <current time>
2   2020-08-16    W_OPEN          NULL        <current time>
2   2020-08-18    W_APPROVED   2020-08-17     <current time>
2   2020-08-19    OPEN            NULL        <current time>
2   2020-08-20    W_OPEN          NULL        <current time>
```

Desired output in DB2 database

```
ID  COL1          STATUS         A_DATE        L_A_DATE              TMST
1   2020-08-08    OPEN            NULL           NULL            <current time>
1   2020-08-10    APPROVED     2020-08-09      2020-08-09        <current time>
1   2020-08-13    OPEN            NULL         2020-08-09        <current time>
1   2020-08-13    A_OPEN          NULL         2020-08-09        <current time>
2   2020-08-08    OPEN            NULL           NULL            <current time>
2   2020-08-13    A_OPEN          NULL           NULL            <current time>
2   2020-08-15    APPROVED     2020-08-14     2020-08-14         <current time>
2   2020-08-16    OPEN            NULL        2020-08-14         <current time>
2   2020-08-16    W_OPEN          NULL        2020-08-14         <current time>
2   2020-08-18    W_APPROVED   2020-08-17     2020-08-17         <current time>
2   2020-08-19    OPEN            NULL        2020-08-17         <current time>
2   2020-08-20    W_OPEN          NULL        2020-08-17         <current time>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the most recent "Approved" value:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when status = 'Approved' then a_date end) over (partition by id order by col1) as l_a_date
from t;
```

Alternatively, you can use a cumulative `max()` (which is another interpretation of what you want):

```
select t.*,
       max(a_date) over (partition by id
                         order by col1 
                         rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                        ) as l_a_date
from t;
```

Comment: This can work for my specific case. But can I get an generic answer for LAG(COL1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TMST ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) which can work in DB2

Comment: @KoushikChandra . . . First, your lag expression doesn't make sense.  Second, this answers the question that you have asked.